# Is cardova mysqlite db.transaction api is synchronous or async?

Tags: android-sqlite

I am using the cardova mysqlite APIs for the usage in ionic. After connecting to the db, am calling db.transaction(insertDB, errorCB, successCB); Is this call a synchronous or async call? I have a log message in insertDB which gets logged after the log which I have written after this statement. Please help me if any of you have faced the same issue.